# Improving MarkLogic Reindexing time

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Is there a way to improve MarkLogic reindexing time specially for a large database(>100TB) in offline cluster with hundreds of forests?

How about disabling local disk failover(replica forests) during re-indexing? Will this reduce reindex time?

Answer (score 3):

Re-Indexing is primarily IO bound.  To improve performance is equivalent to improving IO throughput - so the answers to that are the same.
Since you *do want* to have your replica forests indexed as well you shouldn't disable them -- that just defers the IO to them until you re-enable them.
Since you say this is an 'offline' cluster -- meaning, I presume, that no production traffic is involved so you are free to reconfigure thing that may temporarily interfere with request processing -- this is a good opportunity to learn about tuning IO performance.

IO Performance is a complex subject -- (sorry no simple answers).
First consideration is your physical topology -- what, where, and how are your 'local disks' connected ?  Ex.  If this is in a cloud environemnt or datacenter your 'local disks' may be NAS or network drives in which case your Network IO may be the bottleneck.

Another consideration is the size of your cluster and if you can increase it for this purpose -- that depends on where the forest are located and if they are easy to attach to different servers.

In general, I suggest monitoring both the MarkLogic "Monitoring History" and your OS level performance tools.  The goal is to achive consistant IO activity at near your theroretical capacity but not more.  If you 'push too hard' then you will get a large IO backlogic ( IO queue length ) -- this leads to lots of 'thrash' and eventually such long latency the system may start to time out and retry.

So you need to throttle the reindexing so its not going too hard at once on any one physical disk.  There are many ways to do this, inside marklogic the reindex and merge parameters,  balancing the physical disks wrt to the forest placements, temporarily taking some forests offline and then 'rotating' them into place etc. 
This takes some experimentation to find the right mix.

A final note -- taking "too long" is subjective.  Re-indexing 100TB is a LOT OF IO.  That's going to simply take a LONG LONG Time.  Your goal should be to see how to avoid making it worse, not to try the impossible and make it take less time then it could possibly do.   You can calculate a rough minimum time.  Assume an index requires a complete read and write of all data (it takes a bit more but that's a start).   How long does it take your cluster using other means to read and write 100TB of data?  That's the low bar for a full reindex.
Optimize your OS's base IO throughputs and MarkLogic indexing should follow naturally.